# DSS: Facilitating API authentication for desktop apps

Tags: app, authentication

## desktop-stack-serv

Auth server for desktop applications authenticating with the Stack Exchange API.

### What?

The [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com) enables applications to get data about Stack Exchange sites or
users. It also supports write actions such as creating posts or comments, flagging, voting, and so on. To do the latter,
applications must authenticate to get a write token for a user.

For server-based applications, this is trivial. However, for client-based applications, it's not so easy - either the
application's maintainers must host a web server of their own, or must ask users to go through processes that less
technical users may find difficult.

This project solves that issue by making an open-source token server available. Instead of hosting their own web
server, project maintainers can use this server, which is available at `https://auth.artofcode.co.uk/`.

[Source available on GitHub](https://github.com/ArtOfCode-/desktop-stack-serv).

### How?

Very simple.

- When creating your app on [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/), enter `artofcode.co.uk` as the OAuth domain, and
  enable client-side (implicit) authentication flow.
- Follow the API's [documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication) for using the implicit flow.
  You should use a value of `https://auth.artofcode.co.uk/auth/redirect` for the `redirect_uri` parameter, and you
  should generate a UUID or equivalent random token (a SHA256 hash of a random value, for example). You should pass
  this to the API as the `state` parameter.
- The user authorizes your app, and is redirected to `redirect_uri`. DSS stores the access token against the `state`
  value.
- The user returns to your app, and informs you that they have completed authentication. Your app should now make a
  HTTP GET request to `https://auth.artofcode.co.uk/auth/token?key=<uuid>`, where the value of the `key` parameter is
  the UUID or random token you generated earlier. A JSON object containing one key, `access_token`, will be returned.

### Notes

- Make sure the random token you generate for the `state` parameter is URL-safe.
- **Don't** generate a token based on the current time; that opens the door for app collisions, which could be bad.
- If there's no token stored when you call `/auth/token`, you'll get a JSON object containing `error_name` and
  `error_message` parameters. You'll also get this if you don't pass a `key` parameter.

Comment: Ha! I can't believe you actually went ahead and did this. This is excellent!!

Answer (score 1):

I think, in the name of being cooperative, anybody using this should consider generating a key that is prefixed by their app's client ID, e.g. if your app ID is 3456:

```
3456-<uuid>
```

Sticking to something like this will prevent key collisions.

Also I have an idea for how to implement this in DSS, and I might get a chance to make a PR for it some day, but the idea is:

- Add an optional app ID parameter to `/auth/redirect` e.g.:

  ```
  https://auth.artofcode.co.uk/auth/redirect?appid=3456
  ```

  Note that this can be passed URL encoded to the `redirect_uri` parameter, e.g.:

  ```
  ?redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fauth.artofcode.co.uk%2Fauth%2Fredirect%3Fappid%3D3456
  ```
- So you do that and also pass your random uuid to `state`.
- DSS maintains `accessTokens[appid][state]`.
- And then you request the token from:

  ```
  https://auth.artofcode.co.uk/auth/token?appid=<appid>&key=<uuid>
  ```

This way DSS encourages implicit separation of keyspaces. For laziness/compatibility reasons, `appid` is optional at all points and just uses a global keyspace if not specified (internally the DDS implementation can just pretend it's 0 or something if it's missing).

This should work, and if nobody else does it or nobody has a better idea, one of these days (probably not soon) I'll submit a PR for it.

Comment: Neat idea. I'll have a look at what this requires.